# jQuery Click events not firing on position:absolute <td> tag on iOS after ScrollTop

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile-safari

I've got "Help Docs" on my website for my iPhone App which users view in a UIWebView from within my App. It exhibits some strange behavior. The code below works perfectly on Desktop Safari and Firefox but not mobile Safari. You can see the page here: [My Support Page](http://www.iphemeris.com/support-mobile.html)

The help menu is position:absolute and "Sticky" to the top via some techniques on the web. The code uses all the techniques I can find for getting jQuery to fire on  such as empty onclick="", cursor:pointer on the element. etc. It works first time, but will not scoll to the NEXT thing a user touches UNLESS you manually scroll the page a little.

There are some other similar questions on Stack but none of the suggestions work for me. Any thoughts. This is my jQuery code.

```
$(".help-menu-list-item").on( "click", function(e) {
    $(".help-menu td").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $("html, body").animate(
        {scrollTop: $(".help-item-anchor"+"."+$(this).attr('id')).offset().top}, 'slow'
    );
});
```

NOTE: I DO NOT Think this is a problem with scrollTop. It think it is an issue with getting click events. If I add the jquery alert() to the above jquery block it does not fire unless the page is first manually scrolled a little. So... this is a click event firing issue... BUT I HAVE TRIED many of the tricks to get click events to fire. Can't work out why they will fire first time but not again until after a manual scroll?

- UPDATE *

I ripped out all the jQuery based sticky menus and used the iOS 5 support for:
  position: absolute

along with:
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;

... It yields much simpler code for getting a fixed menu sitting at the top, but the jQuery above STILL has the same problem.... I get the first click event, but NOT those after it scrolls to a position unless user manually scrolls page.

SO... is this jQuery or iOS??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an acknowledged iOS Safari bug related to fixed position elements. I filed an ADC bug report which was acknowledge to be a dupe of #10301184. Consequently I can't track status. I never found a work around.

**Edited Sep. 18, 2012**

**NOTE: I see this bug is now fixed and reported as such in iOS6!! My code is working.**

Answer (score 1):

I just entered this into my inspector console on your page and it worked fine:

```
$('.help-menu-list-item').click(function() {alert("banana")})
```

New edit: Seems like this is a known [jQuery bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5677)

Found this though:

Just add "cursor: pointer" to the element's CSS and the live click event will work as expected.

so maybe try this:

```
$('.help-menu-list-item').css("cursor", "pointer")
```

on document ready, cant test though I have no iPhone :(

Comment: It works fine on regular desktop safari... NOT on Mobile Safari. To see it you will need to Browse there from a safari on your iPhone or iPad or from within the Simulator.  As for the Cursor suggestion I mentioned in the middle of the second para I already tried that... no workie...

Comment: AND.... I should point out, you CANNOT simulate the problem using the Safari Web Inspector on your desktop simulating the Mobile User Agent... Only way to see problem is to view in iOS Simulator OR on a mobile device.

Comment: Ya sorry I noticed that after, but did you see my latest update, I think it is a bug in jQuery

Comment: Might be... but cursor:pointer on the element is not solving it. That is a fairly well known solution to getting Click events to fire on Touch devices... but for whatever reason it is not working always here... if that is in fact the problem. Nor is adding onclick="" working.... but thx

Comment: The root cause of this turned out NOT to be JQuery and was acknowledge by Apple to be a Mobile Safari bug. See my Accepted Answer.